# Anaconda Python - how to reinstall NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, anaconda, conda

I am using Anaconda 5.3.0's Python interpreter in Visual Studio Code. When I try to import `sklearn` I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\azzam\machinelearning.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sklearn
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 10, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

It looks like that I need to "reinstall" NumPy. I searched on the web, but I didn't find a way to "reinstall". There is only how to "install", and when I use

```
conda install numpy
```

in Anaconda Prompt I get:

```
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

And if I tried to remove NumPy to install it again, it will remove everything, not just NumPy. So do I really need to "reinstall" NumPy to be able to import `sklearn`?
And if I do, how do I "reinstall" NumPy?

Comment: Which version of scikit-learn are you using?

Comment: I downloaded Anaconde 5.3.0 for python 3.7, and everything came with it. scikit-learn version is 0.19.2

Comment: Try to update scikit learn by running `conda update scikit-learn `

Comment: I tried to update scikit-learn and it said `All requested packages already installed.` I also tried to update numpy and it did the same `All requested packages already installed.`

Comment: Try `conda install numpy --force`.

Answer (score 115):

How to reinstall a package depends on the conda version.

[newer versions](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html?highlight=force-reinstall) (>= 4.6):

```
conda install numpy --force-reinstall
```

older versions (< 4.6):

```
conda install numpy --force
```

Answer (score 7):

You will most likely have to uninstall NumPy and reinstall it.

```
conda remove numpy
```

And then install it again:

```
conda install -c anaconda numpy
```

Comment: But when I use:
conda remove numpy
It tells me that it will remove a lot, numpy and scikit-learn and a lot of things, and when I install numpy again, it will only install numpy without all things that got deleted

Comment: @user8425571 Hmm, that's interesting. I am not that familiar with `conda`, so that's the best I could come up with. Maybe try removing individual packages?

Comment: `conda remove --force numpy` will ignore the dependencies.

Comment: But that will remove all the depend packages as well?!?

Comment: Nope that only removes NumPy and nothing else :)